# "Mocking" bash functions

Tags: bash, shell, mocking

So I am in need of a way to "mock" a function so that I can intercept it's call - is this a good way to do it?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

connect() {
    echo "connecting to $1 on port $2"
}

setup() {
    connect localhost 8080
}

fake_setup() {
    # Save the original connection function so we can restore it later
    local original_function=$(declare -f connect)

    # Mock the "connect" function so that the real function is not called when
    # we run the setup.
    connect() {
        echo "faking connection to $1 on port $2"
    }

    setup

    eval "${original_function}"
}

# Should output "faking connection to localhost on port 8080".
fake_setup

# Should output "connecting to localhost on port 8080".
setup
```

Are there any alternatives to doing it this way?

Comment: What about using the MIT-licensed [bats-mock](https://github.com/jasonkarns/bats-mock) with [bats](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core), or the Apache-licensed [bash_shell_mock](https://github.com/capitalone/bash_shell_mock)?

Answer (score 2):

make 2 "include" files, both with a `setup()` function in it.
Source the one you need in your script (the mocked one or the real one).

For each interface that you would like to mock, you can have a normal include file and a mocked version. In the main file you just need to decide which version of the include files you want to source.

EDIT: When you want to direct everything from the command line, try keeping the testfile as clean as possible:

File testcase

```
#!/bin/bash

source environ

echo "Calling three functions"
setup
hello
db
```

You want to call `testcase`  without params for no mocking, or something like `testcase db`, `testcase setup` or `testcase setup db`. The parameters will be handled by your `environ` include file:

File environ

```
# Code that sets mocking flags
for param; do                 
   case $param in             
      "hello" ) mockhello=mock;;
      "setup" ) mocksetup=mock;;
      "db" )    mockdb=mock;;   
      * )       echo "No mock supported for $param"
   esac                                            
done                                               

if [ -n "$mockhello" ]; then
   source mockhello         
else                        
   source hello             
fi                          

if [ -n "$mocksetup" ]; then
   source mocksetup         
else                        
   source setup             
fi                          

if [ -n "$mockdb" ]; then
   source mockdb         
else                     
   source db             
fi
```

And you need some files with the real and mocked code:

File db

```
function db {                                              
   echo "Real db"                                          
}
```

File hello

```
function hello {
   echo "Hello"
}
```

File mockdb

```
function db {
   echo "mocking db"
}
```

File mockhello

```
function hello {
   echo "Mocking hello"
}
```

File mocksetup

```
function setup {
   echo "mocking setup"
}
```

File setup

```
function setup {
   echo "setup"
}
```

You only need a `chmod +x testcase` and you are ready to go.

Comment: Well the issue with this is that my "mocking" is actually activated by a flag on the command line and needs to be reverted easily. Think of it as the equivalent of a "dry run" more than a mock for testing.

Comment: In that case, you can just use the flag to determine which definition of `connect` is used: `if [[ $dry_run == yes ]]; then connect () { echo "connecting"; }; else connect () { echo "faking"; }; fi`.

Comment: @chepner: True for a simple case. When you have 20 testcase and 10 interfaces to mock, you want to seperate the mocking from the code. I wouldn't do that using the commandline, but you can make a whole bunch of files for handling the situations. Of course the different include files should be sourced from special folders.